# Filter null value from object

Tags: java

I use this code to get Merchant name by ID.

```
@GetMapping("pages")
public Page<WpfPaymentsDTO> pages(@RequestParam(value = "page") int page, @RequestParam(value = "size") int size) {
    return wpfPaymentsService.findAll(page, size)
                             .filter(g -> g.getMerchant_id() != null)
                             .map(g -> WpfPaymentsDTO.builder()
                             .id(g.getId())
                             .status(g.getStatus())
                             .merchant_id(getMerchantName(g.getMerchant_id()))
                             .build());  
}

private String getMerchantName(Integer id) {      
    return Optional.ofNullable(id)
                   .flatMap(i -> merchantService.findById(i))
                   .map(Merchants::getName)
                   .orElse("");
}
```

But when name is not found I get `java.lang.NullPointerException: null at this line: .merchant_id(getMerchantName(g.getMerchant_id()))` because value `g.getMerchant_id()` is `null` into DB.

Is there a way to filter several null values from the Object?

Comment: I dont think g.getMerchant_id cause nullpointerexceptio, did you use degugger to verify which is the problem exactly?

Comment: it's null into DB.

Comment: Can you add a `filter(Objects::nonNull)` after flatMap please, and let us know what is the result?

Comment: I did but the result is the same.

Comment: I think there are a missing piece in your question!!

Comment: Ok, let me show more https://pastebin.com/9rmyH6dd

Comment: @YCF_L Probably I need to add Lombook configuration?

Comment: @YCF_L Can you give some advice, please?

Comment: First Error `merchant_id` is a String and you try to pass it to method which took an int!

Comment: yes but this is after I resolve the corresponding id -> name

Answer (score 0):

Just create a method in your class, something like `isValid` which returns a boolean. You can add any complex condition in your method. Then use that method in `filter`.

```
private boolean isValid() {
   return getMerchent_id() != null &&  getMerchantName(g.getMerchant_id()) != null
 }
```

Now use this condition in the filter.

```
return wpfPaymentsService.findAll(page, size)
                         .filter(g -> g.isValid())
```

Comment: Updated with example.

Answer (score 0):

It could only be getMerchantName (I think), check the stack trace once more.

```
private String getMerchantName(Integer id) {      
    return Optional.ofNullable(id)
                   .flatMap(i -> merchantService.findById(i))
                   .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                   .map(Merchants::getName)
                   .orElse("");
}
```

Maybe a case of stream overuse.

```
private String getMerchantName(Integer id) {      
    return id == null ? ""
        : merchantService.findById(id.intValue()) // Stream / Optional?
                   .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                   .map(Merchants::getName)
                   .filter(Objects::nonNull) // When there are null names.
                   .orElse("");
}
```

Comment: Honestly said I would expect twice the nonNull filter (if applicable to `findById`) to remove any NPE, but without real idea.

Comment: The first solution is not working. For the second I get The operator == is undefined for the argument type(s) int, null

Comment: @Peter Penzov use Objects.isNull(s)

Comment: @YCF_L Can you show me example please? Which line and how I need to modify?

Comment: Just change id == null by Objects.nonNull(id)

Comment: It's not solving the issue.

Comment: Okay. First a rebuild: do it in pieces. So you can better narrow it down. You might tell the readers what findById returns, `Optional<Merchant>`? I expect it to be something simple.

Comment: Yes, it returns Optional<Merchant>